# How to configure Bean Validation with Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I am trying to configure Spring : `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` to set my custom `TraversableResolver`

I do the following in my *applicationContext.xml* :

```
<bean id="customTraversableResolver" class="com.package.core.resolver.SimpleTraversableResolver" />

<bean id="validator"
    class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <property name="traversableResolver" ref="customTraversableResolver" />
</bean>
```

But at runtime, `@Valid` bean in controller are validated with default traversable resolver (from hibernate validator).
So, how to configure default bean validation configuration in spring ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding validation.xml and adding the traversable resolver configuration in there? Btw, what do you want to achieve with your custom resolver?

Comment: It works ! Thanks. But why is not configurable by spring without XML config ?

Answer (score 0):

While you’re using Spring MVC, you must register your validator in this way:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator" />
```

If you want method-level validation, then define bean:

```
<!-- Enable method-level validation on annotated methods via JSR-303 -->
<bean class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor"
      p:validatorFactory-ref="validator" />
```

Then you don’t need `validator.xml` anymore.

*Note: This works with Spring 3.2.x and Hibernate Validator 4.x.*